# how to sort by a custom appended relation to model

Tags: php, laravel

i have a custom appended relation to model that i want to sort my parents according to that so this is the result of my api when i call it :

```
  {
            "id": 3,
            "operator_id": 12,
            "created_at": "2019-05-22 19:20:02",
            "updated_at": "2019-07-31 18:50:53",
            "hits": 4,
            "cheapest_room": {
                "id": 1,              
                "accommodation_id": 3,
                "bed_count": 1,  
                "name": null,
                "english_name": null,
                "description": null,
                "english_description": null,
                "created_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-06-30 17:05:18",
                "accommodation_room_id": 1,
                 // this is the field i want to sort by
                "sales_price": 100,
                "from_date": "2019-05-25 00:00:00",
                "to_date": "2019-08-30 23:59:59"
            }
```

i am using spatie query builder for sorting and filtering this but i want to do a sort on sales_price on cheapest room object this is my code below :

```
  public function scopeFilter(){
        $data = QueryBuilder::for(Accommodation::class)
            ->allowedAppends(['cheapestroom'])
            ->allowedIncludes(['gallery','city','accommodationRooms','accommodationRooms.roomPricingHistorySearch','discounts'])
            ->allowedSorts([
                AllowedSort::custom('discount', new DiscountSort() ,'amount'),
                'discounts.amount'
            ])
            ->allowedFilters([
            AllowedFilter::scope('bed_count'),
            AllowedFilter::scope('filter_price'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('grade_stars'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('city_id'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('is_recommended'),
            AllowedFilter::exact('accommodation_type_id'),
            'name',
            ])
            ->paginate(10);

        return $data;
    }
```

in short form i want to sort my api based on sales price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should Use A join like below which will give you All things according to your needs

```
  $data = $query->join('accommodation_rooms', 'accommodations.id', '=', 'accommodation_rooms.accommodation_id')
            ->join('discounts', 'accommodation_rooms.id', '=', 'discounts.accommodation_room_id')
            ->select('accommodation_rooms.id')
            ->orderBy('discounts.amount', 'desc')
            ->select('discounts.amount', 'accommodations.*')
            ->groupBy('discounts.amount', 'accommodation_rooms.id');
        return $data;
```

after that you can user it in your filters like below :

```
    ->allowedSorts([
                AllowedSort::custom('discount', new DiscountSort() ,'amount'),
            ])
```

Comment: thats you saved my day i should use joins instead of query builder thanks man

Comment: I don't think `allowedSorts` will work if you start using Model Query instead of spatie QueryBuilder

Answer (score 1):

i have done this by adding this

```
->with('cheapest_room')
->allowedSorts(['cheapest_room.sales_price'])
```

Comment: why when i use it , it says it cannot find colomn sales_price are you sure you used for sorting that ???

Comment: this is the message i get exaclty :     "message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'accommodation_rooms.bed_count' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from `accommodations` order by `accommodation_rooms`.`bed_count` asc limit 10 offset 0)",

Comment: i tried some other relation that i was sure that it exist on the model but its the same with the relation i wrote above in question

Comment: but that error is for bed_count  in accomodatio_rooms can you show us all fields of the db

Comment: yes but look at the query it just selects the accommodation not the accommodationroom i know that that fields exist in table for sure

Answer (score 1):

I face the same issue as you.
I wanted to sort by the relationship
The best solution I found is to use `join`

```
public function scopeFilter(){
    $data = QueryBuilder::for(Accommodation::class)
        ->allowedAppends(['cheapestroom'])
        ->allowedIncludes(['gallery','city','accommodationRooms','accommodationRooms.roomPricingHistorySearch','discounts'])
        ->allowedSorts([
            AllowedSort::custom('discount', new DiscountSort() ,'amount'),
            'discounts.amount'
        ])
        ->join('accommodation_rooms', 'accommodations.id', '=', 'accommodation_rooms.accommodation_id')
        ->join('discounts', 'accommodation_rooms.id', '=', 'discounts.accommodation_room_id')
        ->select('accommodation_rooms.id')
        ->orderBy('discounts.amount', 'desc')
        ->select('discounts.amount', 'accommodations.*')
        ->paginate(10);

    return $data;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If Accommodation class have cheapest_room relation, You should check out the sample code from [SortTest.php#L90-103](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder/blob/8a723a26b80f1095d115fe42091e82183379a5ff/tests/SortTest.php#L90-L103)

```
public function it_can_sort_a_query_by_a_related_property()
{
    $request = new Request([
        'sort' => 'related_models.name',
        'includes' => 'relatedModel',
    ]);
    $sortedQuery = QueryBuilder::for(TestModel::class, $request)
        ->allowedIncludes('relatedModels')
        ->allowedSorts('related_models.name')
        ->toSql();
    $this->assertEquals('select * from "test_models" order by "related_models"."name" asc', $sortedQuery);
}
```

Try

```
$query->allowedSorts('cheapest_room.sales_price')
```

If you have complex query for cheapest_room property, You should define [custom sort](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder/blob/f018faacba78513d536620133e4ec530b8b6a1b2/docs/features/sorting.md#custom-sorts), See https://github.com/spatie/laravel-query-builder/pull/91#issue-208809827 for detail.

```
class CheapestPriceSort implements \Spatie\QueryBuilder\Sorts\Sort
{
    public function __invoke(Builder $query, bool $descending, string $property)
    {
        $query->... // Run {join,sub} query with $query
        return $query->orderBy('cheapest_room.sales_price', $descending ? 'desc' : 'asc');
    }
}
```

Comment: no this is not working it gives me the error colomn not found even though i have the relationship and i loaded that in my api

Comment: @Farshad Provide more information about Accommodation class and table schema

Comment: what do you need consider all the data in api above the acoomodation models data